# Publish Net Core app to azurewebsites.net using Azure CLI with PublishSettings

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am trying to publish a .Net Core app to Azure with `myapp.PublishSettings` using Azure CLI, but I can't find the command to do this

I think that it may be with `az webapp update` but I don't see where can I enter my PublishSettings reading the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PublishSettings is for when you want to publish directly from visual studio. Whereas azure cli is command line interface for general use meaning it can be used to automate your CI/CD pipeline from any where not necessarily from your PC. So, it has got different parameters and supports everything that is supported by PublishSettings. For example you can use `az webapp up` to deploy code and to change app settings of the web app you can use `az webapp config appsettings set`. Unfortunately, there isn't an option to pass publishsettings as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also wasn't able to find any way to do it

Comment: @rohit Thank you for your answer. The Azure Cloud Shell requires me to sign in with an Azure account, Visual Studio does not: it simply only needs a PublishSettings. Do you know whether it's possible to publish from the cli without having to sign in?

Comment: @carucel : It may appear that visual studio does not require login but its not true. The publish settings file has app service login and password. A standard use case is to publish website as part of CI/CD pipeline. In that case you would use a service connection which is created using client id and secret on the Azure DevOps. But, if you want to do it from your pc, you will have to login using an account.